# How can I individually change the decimal place of a select few axis labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple plot below. I log scaled the x-axis and I want the graph to show 0.1, 1, 10. I can't figure out how to override the default of 0.1, 1.0, 10.0.

Is there a way I could change only two of the x-axis labels?

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(0.1, 1, 10)
y <- c(1, 5, 10)


ggplot()+

  geom_point(aes(x,y)) +

  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: You can change with `labels` `scale_x_log10(breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
    labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x))+ )`

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify `labels` and `breaks` in `scale_x_log10`

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(0.1, 1, 10)
y <- c(1, 5, 10)

ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x,y)) + scale_x_log10(labels = x, breaks = x)
```

[image]